# How many free parameters can there be in the mass matrix of the $X$ bosons?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

Let the GUT symmetry $SU(5)$ break spontaneously to $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$ at a scale $M$ much higher than the masses of $Z$ and $W$ bosons. Then, at this scale, $Z$, $W$ bosons can be regardedless virtually massless (let alone other lighter particles) so that $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$ can be regarded as unbroken.

Then, how many free parameters can the mass matrix of the $X$ bosons, the gauge bosons of GUT, can have? I heard that there are 12 kinds of $X$ bosons. However, I cannot find an argument to derive the number. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Goldstone theorem the result is immediate since $SU(5)$ has $N^2-1 = 24$ generators, when the symmetry is spontaneously broken $$SU(5)\to SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$$ we remain with $(3^2-1)+(2^2-1)+1 = 12$ generators which means that $12$ out of the $24$ gauge bosons become massless Goldstone bosons, which are the $Z^0_\mu$ and $W^\pm_\mu$ of the $SU(2)$, the $A_\mu$ of $U(1)$ and the $8$ gluons of $SU(3)$, whilst the remaining $12$ are the massive $X$ bosons.

Comment: So, is the number of free parameters $12$ as well?

Comment: In order to give (though possibly degenerate) $12$ masses?

Comment: Yes, there remain $12$ free parameters with possibly degenerate spectrum

Comment: Then, the number of 'independent masses' may be less than 12, due to possibly degeneracy. Is this correct too?